# EntityFramework core migrations for Identity Server4

Tags: identityserver4

We using EntityFramework Core with Identity Server4. And we have added class library(.NET Core) for store EntityFramework configurations and migrations. After run the following command

dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerPersistedGrantDbMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb

We have got the following error:

**The specified framework version '2.0' could not be parsed
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      \
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.0'.**

Comment: Did you install the framework version '2.0'?

Comment: yes i have install but still facing the same problem

Comment: actually i am trying to install EntityFramework Core migration in the .NET Core library(just for separation). When i tried with .NET Core Applications its working fine.

Comment: Does your .csproj file contain this line: <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>

Comment: yes this is exist.

Comment: but still facing the same problem